# OTA Application Provisioning implementation on Android

Tags: android, ota, oma

i am trying to implement OTA settings update for my app.
didn't find any tutorial regarding this issue.
the settings file would be an XML file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in "OTA settings update" in Android.

If "OTA settings update" implies an update to your application itself, download the APK to external storage and call `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, a `Uri` pointing to that (world-readable), and the magic MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`).

If "OTA settings update" is data, download what you want from your Web server.

Comment: Hi commonsware I didn't got your point so please can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: @AshwinNBhanushali...did you found any solution to implement OTA update from locally configured server apart from google play.